# check List <int> A contains elements from list B, with repeated values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to check if `List<int>` A contains all values available on `List<int> B`

But I need to be sure that not only values are correct but also their count, if A is real subset of B.

I found solution like this, but both gives wrong answer:

```
List <int> A = new List <int>(){1,1,2,3}; 
List <int> B = new List <int>(){1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9};

bool c = A.All(B.Contains);
bool d = !A.Except(B).Any();
Console.WriteLine(c); //True
Console.WriteLine(d); //True
```

List A can't be subset of list B, because it contains double value 1;

How can I handle with repeated values?

More examples

```
A = {1,2,3}; 
B = {1,2,3,4,5};
A is a subset of B => True

A = {1,1,2,3,2}; 
B = {1,1,2,2,3,4,5};
A is a subset of B => True

A = {1,2,3}; 
B = {1,1,2,2,3,4,5};
A is a subset of B => True
```

but:

```
A = {1,2,2,3}; 
B = {1,2,3,4,5};
A is not a subset of B => False
```

Comment: It looks like you're actually checking if B contains all the values in A.

Comment: So, if 1 occurs twice in `A` this should return false, because 1 must only occur once in `B`?

Comment: @Marco yes! I want them to be with same values and same or number (if there are some repetitions

Comment: @eudaimonia The same or just less, so if B has 3 1's and A has 2 then that should return true?

Comment: @juharr  sorry - if B has 3 x ones and A has 2 x ones this is correct, because B contains all elements of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your samples, I understood that you want to preserve duplicates....
Try as said below....

```
 List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
 List<int> b = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,2};

 IEnumerable<int> both = Intersect2(a,b);

 if (a.Count() == both.Count())
 {
    int i1 = 0;
     //Subset
 }
```

And the Intersect2 method looks as shown below

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect2<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
    {
         List<T> list = target.ToList();
         foreach (T item in source)
         {
             if (list.Contains(item))
             {
                list.Remove(item);
                yield return item;
             }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to group the values and check the counts.

```
var bCounts = B.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Count());
bool aIsSubsetOfB = A.GroupBy(x=>x)
    .All(g => bCounts.ContainsKey(g.Key) && bCounts[g.Key] > g.Count());
```

Comment: I added some e.g above. This count values but will not work for some ease set like A = 1,2,3  B = 1,2,3,4 - and in that case A is a subset of B

Comment: @eudaimonia That case would result in true.  Is that not what you want?  In fact this will return the desired results for each case.  Did you even try it?